# How do I find out what's buffering the communication from qemu to pexpect?

Tags: qemu, pexpect

I have a Python2 program that runs qemu with a FreeBSD image.
`expect()`ing lines out output works.
However, `expect()`ing output that does not have its line terminated (such as when waiting for a prompt like `login:`) does not, this times out.

I suspect something in the communication between qemu and my program is doing line buffering, but how do I find out which of them it is? Candidates that I can think of:

- FreeBSD itself. I find that unlikely, it shows prompts when running interactively, and qemu's `-nographics` options shouldn't make a difference for the emulated VM (but I may be wrong).
- Something in the setup of the pty. I have zero experience with ptys. If that's the issue, this would be a bug in pexpect since pexpect is setting the pty up.
- A bug in pexpect.
- Something in my own script... but I have no clue what that could be.

For reference, here's the stripped-down code (including download and unpack, should anybody want to play with it):

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python2

import os
import pexpect
import re
import sys
import time

def run(cmd):
    '''Run command, log to stdout, no timeout, return the status code.'''
    print('run: ' + cmd)
    (output, rc) = pexpect.run(
        cmd,
        withexitstatus=1,
        encoding='utf-8',
        logfile=sys.stdout,
        timeout=None
        )
    if rc != 0:
        print('simple.py: Command failed with return code: ' + rc)
        exit(rc)


download_path = 'https://download.freebsd.org/ftp/releases/VM-IMAGES/12.0-RELEASE/amd64/Latest'
image_file = 'FreeBSD-12.0-RELEASE-amd64.qcow2'
image_file_xz = image_file + '.xz'

if not os.path.isfile(image_file_xz):
    run('curl -o %s %s/%s' % (image_file_xz, download_path, image_file_xz))

if not os.path.isfile(image_file):
    # Reset image file to initial state
    run('xz --decompress --keep --force --verbose ' + image_file_xz)

#cmd = 'qemu-system-x86_64 -snapshot -monitor none -display curses -chardev stdio,id=char0 ' + image_file
cmd = 'qemu-system-x86_64 -snapshot -nographic ' + image_file
print('interact with: ' + cmd)
child = pexpect.spawn(
    cmd,
    timeout=90, # FreeBSD takes roughly 60 seconds to boot
    maxread=1,
    )
child.logfile = sys.stdout

def expect(pattern):
    result = child.expect([pexpect.TIMEOUT, pattern])
    if result == 0:
        print("timeout: %d reached when waiting for: %s" % (child.timeout, pattern))
        exit(1)
    return result - 1

if False:
    # This does not work: the prompt is not visible, then timeout
    expect('login: ')
else:
    # Workaround, tested to work:
    expect(re.escape('FreeBSD/amd64 (freebsd)')) # Line before prompt
    time.sleep(1) # MUCH longer than actually needed, just to be safe

child.sendline('root')

# This will always time out, and terminate the script
expect('# ')
print('We want to get here but cannot')
```

Comment: Find out the pty on which `qemu` is running and run `stty` to get its settings (e.g. `stty -a -F /dev/pts/4`).

Comment: @EmilyE. I have tried to understand the output of `stty -a`, but I couldn't find a useful reference. How do I know which `stty` options, if any, influence output buffering? (`extproc` seems to be related in some way, but its effect isn't explained :-( )

Comment: extproc is described at http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-readline/2011-01/msg00004.html.